# Filling Combo/ListBox with file names from a directory

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm attempting to populate a `ListBox` with file names from a directory. My code works, however, when I recompile the program the items are no longer there. Also when I click on an item in the `ListBox` the content of the `ListBox` is duplicated over and over.  Any guidance would be much appreciated, thanks.

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(".\\Notes\\");
    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.txt");
    foreach ( FileInfo file in files )
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've populated your `ListBox` in the incorrect event. So each time you select an item, the `ListBox` is populated again. You should put it in another event like `Button_Click` or `Form_load`:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(".\\Notes\\");
    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.txt");
    foreach ( FileInfo file in files )
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(file);
    }
}

//Or in a Button_Click event
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(".\\Notes\\");
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to the advice of @S.Akbari my solution to my issue is below.

```
      public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
             DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(".\\Notes\\");
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.txt");
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(file);
        }

    }
```